# Redirect url in Django 1.4.5

Tags: django, url, redirect, qr-code

I have a QR code that points to a URL in my site that doesn't exist. I don't want to create a page just for that QR code, rather just redirect the user to the home page. I'm currently on Django 1.4.5 and I'm sure there must be a simple solution to this.

One thing I did find was this which I'm putting in my urls.py file:

```
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^bad-QR-url/not-here$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/')),
```

However this doesn't seem to work. Is this code for Django 1.5? Anyway, any help would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: why dont you use a 404 ?

Comment: These QR codes are on the backs of people's business cards so it'd be a bit embarrassing for them to bring up an error 404 page. That is unless I'm not fully understanding.

Comment: it's a normal behavior for page that are not found [you can have a look at this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/views/#the-http404-exception) which use a try/catch

Answer (score 1):

Write your own 404 handler or change the QR view behaviour by overwriting the get_object function.

```
class QRView(DetailView):
    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        """
        Returns the object the view is displaying.

        By default this requires `self.queryset` and a `pk` or `slug` argument
        in the URLconf, but subclasses can override this to return any object.
        """
        # Use a custom queryset if provided; this is required for subclasses
        # like DateDetailView
        if queryset is None:
            queryset = self.get_queryset()

        # Next, try looking up by primary key.
        pk = self.kwargs.get(self.pk_url_kwarg, None)
        slug = self.kwargs.get(self.slug_url_kwarg, None)
        if pk is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(pk=pk)

        # Next, try looking up by slug.
        elif slug is not None:
            slug_field = self.get_slug_field()
            queryset = queryset.filter(**{slug_field: slug})

        # If none of those are defined, it's an error.
        else:
            raise AttributeError(u"Generic detail view %s must be called with "
                                 u"either an object pk or a slug."
                                 % self.__class__.__name__)

        try:
            obj = queryset.get()
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            # REDIRECT GOES HERE.
        return obj
```

Comment: I should probably point out that I am a Django nubcake who hadn't even heard of Django a couple of months ago. I'm sure your solution works but it's going right over my head. There are four business cards with four differing QR codes that used to point to some sort of bio page about the card holder. Is there not a simple sulution I can put into urls.py?